# Binding Element at Path formatting in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm user a custom user control that is a special type of slider. I can get the lower and upper values from the binding of the object like such:

```
{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=LowerValue};
{Binding ElementName=slider, Path=UpperValue};
```

I would like to reformat this number before putting into a `Label`. I've tried embedding some c# directly into my WPF, but I'm not sure how to get the values back in c#. Here's what I've tried which doesn't work:

```
<![CDATA[
                double min = {Binding ElementName=slider, Path=LowerValue};
                double max = {Binding ElementName=slider, Path=UpperValue};


                if (min == 1) { label.Content = "24:00:00"; }
                else { label.Content = TimeSpan.FromHours(min).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); }

                if (max == 1) { label_Copy.Content = "24:00:00"; }
                else { label_Copy.Content = TimeSpan.FromHours(max).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); }
            ]]>
    </x:Code>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean by "I've tried embedding some c# directly into my WPF, but I'm not sure how to get the values back in c#." ?

Comment: So you can embed C# directly into WPF xaml file. So I just thought that would be easier since there's probably a way for me to get the binding values directly there... I'm just not sure how

Comment: as mentioned in my answer ,you can use converter for that.why do you want to embed code in xaml?

Comment: I just thought it would be easier. I'm trying your answer now.

Comment: Even though XAML has flexibility to consume C# code,it is in fact not at all recommended to be used in practice. In terms of architecture, it is always preferred to separate the designer and the code to keep developer and designer roles distinct. On the other hand XAML does not have intellisense defined in designer, so it is really messy to write code in XAML itself. You cannot add using statements inside XAML too, leading to use long fully qualified naming of classes etc. ..Hope this helps you to have better understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Define a converter that casts the value as slider & returns the formatted text:

```
public class SliderToContentConverter:IValueConverter
{
  ....Convert(object value,...)
  {
     var slider =value as slider;
     if(slider!=null)
     {
      double min = slider.LowerValue;
      double max = slider.UpperValue;
      if (min == 1) 
         { return "24:00:00"; }
      else
         { return TimeSpan.FromHours(min).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); }
      if (max == 1) 
         { return "24:00:00"; }
      else {  return TimeSpan.FromHours(max).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss"); 
      }
     return null;
   }
}
```

2.Add the converter in Resources with a key.
3.Add binding for Label.Content:

```
<Label x:name=label_copy Content={Binding ElementName=slider,Converter={StaticResource con}/>
```

Comment: I get the error message the resource SliderToContentConverter.con could not be resolved. How am I supposed to refer to it?

Comment: In the container window, add the converter as resource:<Windows.Resources><local:SliderToContentConverter x:key="con"/></Windows.Resoources> where local will be the namespace for the converter class, you need to define in the XAML initial section ,similar to xmlns:local= "clr-namespace WindowsApplicationXX"

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is a lot easier if you use MVVM. Create a view model and add your two properties along with an update function:

```
public class TestViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _TimeVal;
    public int TimeVal
    {
        get { return this._TimeVal; }
        set
        {
            this._TimeVal = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TimeVal);
            UpdateText();
        }
    }

    private string _TimeText;
    public string TimeText
    {
        get { return this._TimeText; }
        set { this._TimeText = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.TimeText); }
    }

    public TestViewModel()
    {
        UpdateText(); // force initial value
    }

    private void UpdateText()
    {
        this.TimeText = TimeSpan.FromHours(this.TimeVal).ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss");
    }
}
```

Then in your XAML you simply bind to those properties:

```
<Slider Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding TimeVal}"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TimeText}" />
```